# Getting a String from another form

Tags: java

I have a `JList` inside a `JDialog` that contains names, by double-clicking a name it should get the name somehow and insert it to a String inside another form, basically I know how to do it with when only one form is using this `JDialog` (`Main.setSelectedName(...)`), but I'm having a hard time implementing it the usage of two or more forms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not try a : public static variables

Answer (score 0):

create some "holder" object and use it as "clipboard" in another forms

Comment: isn't there any way to use like an input message?

Comment: @Tal what do you mean by "input message"?